# xhtml page don't work with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, xhtml

I use springSecurity in my web-app. Any reguest should be redirected to /login:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

    <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            login-processing-url="/app/checkuser"
            default-target-url="/app/main"
            authentication-failure-url="/app/login?login_failed=1"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/app/login" logout-url="/app/logout"/>
</http>
```

but it doesn't work. Page login.xhtml exists in WEB-INF/views. Configuration files in dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.sombra.test.training"/>
```

And include dispatcher-servlet.xml in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: If I come to faces/index.xhtml it doesn't redirect to login.xhtml